# tool to help create a class registration system

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, registration

Does anyone have advise or can recommend a tool or CMS system with a plugin or ability where user's could register multiple people (children) for classes online?

I'm not looking for anything turn-key, and I'm expecting to need to code some of this in by hand, create a plugin or otherwise.

Concept would be parent registers as a user, creates child objects (ha!), then assigns children to classes by schedule.  Classes would have a registration limit, etc.  I've seen a number of commercial, SaaS, and other tools to do event registration, this would be for like registering a child in a semester long class that has meeting times, etc.

I'm looking for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group I was looking at this for did find exactly what they needed in an affordable commercial solution.  Other commercial solutions allowed for "event" registration, but like I said, this was a semester long class, etc.  They found a site called www.studioware-online.com that provides this service.  It's not exactly what I thought they would go with, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all of it's capabilities, but you might take a look at [Moodle](http://moodle.org/). It probably has *waaay* more than you need, but you can probably ignore the parts that don't fit your problem.

**Update:** I did a quick google on *open source course registration* and found a lot of stuff. [UNESCO](http://www.unesco-ci.org/cgi-bin/portals/foss/page.cgi?d=1&g=18) has a nice list of packages. And then there's the [Sakai Project](http://www.sakaiproject.org/), which was originated at Stanford in 2003. Again, probably way more than you need, but ...

Comment: I should have mentioned that I looked at Moodle.  It just does seem more than is needed.  I'm going to see if it will do what I need, and just disable everything else.  Thanks!